# Running a bookkeeping script (sh) the entire user session

Tags: command-line, session

I have a script that does some bookkeeping. This bookkeeping is done after a specified time interval, say 30 minutes.

I want the script to be active from the moment a user logs in until the user logs off.

At the moment the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    #do some stuff
    sleep 1800
done
```

I don't know how I can configure my system to automatically start executing this script (especially in a multi threaded fashion since the script will never stop).

Another problem is how this script should end it's execution. Basically the stuff should be done atomatically: better not doing in than a user who logs off in the middle of the execution. Furthermore the script should not stall the log off process until the entire script is executed (something that will never happen).

How can I achieve these two goals?

I know the script isn't that accurate with time (since the stuff itself will take some seconds, after a while, the loop will not be executed each 30 minutes), but that doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/311352/147044) to see how to run a script at startup (after you are login in GUI).

Relating to the second part of request, I don't think that you will find an easy way to prevent the log off process. Something easy that you can do is to send some notifications on the screen when sleep time ended:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    notify-send -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal)" "Updating bookkeeping!"
    #do some stuff
    notify-send -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal)" "Update of bookkeeping will start again in 30 minutes."
    sleep 1800
done
```