# How do I show a message with username and date at login?

Tags: bash, bashrc

How to show the message "hello $username, today's date is $date" as soon as you login to Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want this to happen in text mode or to prompt a messagebox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/showing-a-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux will help you if you're aware of shell scripts.

Comment: Are you logging in via GUI or commandline?

Comment: Take a look at [Writing shell scripts](http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to see the message when you open the terminal or after you are login in tty1-6, just put this line at the end of `~/.bashrc` file (open it from terminal with `gedit ~/.bashrc`):

```bsh
echo "Hello $USER, today's date is $(date +"%A, %d-%m-%y")"
```

If you want to see the message after you are login in GUI, do the following:

1. Create a new file `name_and_date.sh`:

   ```
   gedit ~/bin/name_and_date.sh
   ```
2. If you want to get a desktop notification, put next 2 lines inside:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   notify-send "Hello" "Hello $USER, today's date is $(date +"%A, %d-%m-%y")"
   ```

   Alternatively, if you want a popup (message box) to show up, put next 2 lines inside:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   zenity --info --title "Hello" --text "Hello $USER, today's date is $(date +"%A, %d-%m-%y")"
   ```
3. Save the file and close it.
4. Make the file exacutable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/bin/name_and_date.sh
   ```
5. Search in **Dash** for **Startup Applications**, open it and click **Add**.
6. Under name type "Show my name and date" or something you will recognise.
7. Under command type: `/home/$USER/bin/name_and_date.sh` (change `$USER` with your user name).
8. Under comment (if you want), type a brief description.

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

Comment: That would be `~/.bashrc` not `~/bashrc`. Excellent tutorial for creating a startup application.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for attention, I was hurried. I will correct now.

Comment: I want to be picky: don't use the suffix `.sh` for a [tag:bash] script, it's confusing! Otherwise good answer! `+1`.