# Is there any way to set a greeting message in ubuntu?

Tags: startup

I love a quote. Now I want every time my computer starts, the quote to be on the screen, like a welcome note.Is there any way to do that in ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could pop up a simple zenity dialog on login with the content of your quote.

Put the following code into a script then add that script to your "Startup Applications"

```
zenity --info --text=$quote --title="A Quote"
```

---

### Using `fortune`

Install the `fortune-mod` package (`sudo apt-get install fortune-mod`) then you can integrate the `fortune` command into your script like this:

```
zenity --info --text="$(fortune literature)" --title="A Quote" --no-wrap
```

You can just add that command to your Startup Applications without putting it in a script.

The `literature` option is used to specify that you want a quote specifically, otherwise it will give you jokes, riddles and other 'fortunes'.

Note: some of the fortunes are quite long, use `--text="$(fortune -s literature)"` instead of `--text="$(fortune literature)"` in the command above to print short quotes only.

Screenshot below:
[image: Fortunes in a dialog]

Fortune also has many different options to customize the type of quotes you'll get (literature, riddles, etc.) See the [fortune man page](http://linux.die.net/man/6/fortune) for more information. To use those options, just change `fortune` in the command above to `fortune SOME_OPTION`.

[Credits to FreudianSlip for the `fortune` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358421/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-greeting-message-in-ubuntu/358423#comment458824_358423)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still true, but in unix's of old, the "fortune" command would offer many different phrases/sayings.  I'm not on a linux/unix box to test right now, but im sure you'll find references to it.

Comment: http://lost.sourceforge.net/ works with Fortune to improve your sysadminish skillz.

Comment: @kiloseven of course, you could replace the `fortune` command with whatever info-like command you have (can find).

Comment: The last argument that the fortune command takes is an optional file/directory name, so you can create and use your own collection of quotes. I don't remember the exact file format, but it's a very simple text file you can easily maintain using a text editor.

Comment: If you go with a pop-up, also take a look at yad. It's a zenity replacement with many more features and great support.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to fancy things up (like show a transparent quote on your wallpaper, type in some reminders etc...):

1. Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Go to "Edit > Profiles > New".
3. Give it a **name** (eg, "quote_of_the_day") and click **Create**.
4. Click Edit, go to the colors tab and uncheck "use colors from ...".
5. Select a **text color** which will be visible on your desktop wallpaper.
6. Go to **background** tab and select **Transparent Background** and set it to None.
7. Under **Scrolling** tab choose "Scrollbar is: **Disabled**".
8. You can change font and size from general tab.
9. Here you may also change **columns and rows** to about 50 and 5 respectively.
10. Go to **Title and Command** and choose **keep initial title** from the combo box.

Now you've made a terminal profile for the quotes display.
[image]

Next we will make a compiz setting to put it in our desktop background and remove those shadows and decorations.

- Open Compiz Config by typing in terminal **`ccsm`** (assuming you have it installed)
- Click **Window Rules** and do the following:
  [image]
- Click **Place Windows** and do the following:
  [image]
- ***Note***: the 600 x and 100 y positions should be changed according to your screen resolution. (this puts it somewhere in the top right corner)
- Go to **Window Decoration** and do the following:
  [image]

Now copy and paste the below script in to gedit and save it as **quote_script.py**

```
import commands
from time import sleep
import random

quotefile = "/home/user/Documents/.../quotes.txt"
interval = 10

with open(quotefile,'rb') as data: quotes = data.readlines()
print "\x1b[?25l"+random.choice(quotes)[:-1]
sleep(interval)
exit()
```

*Change **quotefile** and **interval** to suit your file location and quote display time.*
Go to **startup applications** by typing in terminal : **gnome-session-properties**. Add a new one by clicking **add** and type in:

- **Name**:

  > Daily Quotes
- **Command**:

  ```
  gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=quote_of_the_day -e "python /home/user/Documents/.../quote_script.py"
  ```
- **Comment**:

  > Show random quotes at login

*That's it! You may try logging out and in again to see the result.*

## Final Result:

[image]

 ***- Experiment with terminal column and row values; Position values, interval, font colors etc. Remember to put quotes in quotes.txt file line by line.***

Comment: Nice answer, and better with python, but not the easiest or simplest answer. I would also suggest disabling 'No focus' and adding a `input("Press enter...")` to dismiss the dialog manually. Also, isn't `'rb'` read **binary** mode?

Comment: yes, a good practice for reading unicode characters, control characters etc. `r` just reads plain text and `\n`,`\t`. Also, the quote disappears automatically in 10 secs (user set).

Answer (score 2):

Let say that you have all your quotes in one file called `quotes.txt` (each quote on one line) saved somewhere, let say in `~/Documents`. Then, using [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) you can do:

1. Create a new file/script `greeting.sh` in your `~/bin` directory:

   ```bsh
   mkdir -p ~/bin #this command will make a bin directory in your home folder if you don't already have it
   gedit ~/bin/greetings.sh
   ```
2. If you want to get a desktop notification, put next 2 lines inside:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   quotes="$HOME/Documents/quotes.txt"
   random_line=$(shuf -i 1-$(wc -l < $quotes) -n 1)
   quote=$(sed -n -e "$random_line"p $quotes)
   notify-send "Quote of the day" "$quote"
   ```

   Alternatively, if you want a popup (message box) to show up, use `zenity` instead `notify-send`:

   ```bsh
   zenity --info --title  "Quote of the day" --text "$quote"
   ```
3. Save the file and close it.
4. Make the file exacutable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/bin/greetings.sh
   ```
5. Search in **Dash** for **Startup Applications**, open it and click **Add**.
6. Under name type "Show my name and date" or something you will recognise.
7. Under command type: `/home/$USER/bin/greetings.sh` (change `$USER` with your user name).
8. Under comment (if you want), type a brief description.

Related: [How do I show a message with username and date at login?](https://askubuntu.com/a/311352/147044)

Comment: Your script can be simplified by just using `quote=$(shuf -n 1 "$quotes")` -- no need for the sed or wc calls, since `shuf -n 1 file` will give you a random line from a file all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple answers here, none was simple enough for me.

I ended up installing [Variety](https://peterlevi.com/variety/), which can nicely write random quotes on wallpapers for different sources, in my case from a local file.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This answer would be much improved if you were to actually explain how one goes about writing random quotes on wallpapers with Variety.